# Finding Fourier series of cosh

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have to find an even Fourier series (i.e. only cosine-terms) of $$f(x)=\cosh(x-1)$$ in the interval $0 \leq x \leq 1$ with periodicity 2.

(EDIT: With my calculated Fourier coefficients I end up with
$$f(x)=\frac{\sinh(2)}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n \sinh(2)}{1+\pi^2 n^2}\cos(\pi n x)$$
because the series is supposed to be even.)

(EDIT 2: For $f(x)=\text{cosh}(1-|x|)$, $|x| < 1$, we get
$$a_n = \frac{2e\pi n\sin(\pi n)+e^2-1}{e \pi^2 n^2 +e}=\frac{e^2-1}{e\pi^2 n^2 +e}$$
Therefore we get
$$f(x)=\frac{e^2 -1}{2e}+\sum_{n \geq1} \frac{e^2-1}{e\pi^2 n^2 +e}\cos(\pi n x)$$

I just quickly used WolframAlpha.)

With that I have to show, that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2 +1}=\frac{1}{e^2-1}$$

I've got trouble with the limits of integration because the length of the interval isn't equal to 2. We never had such an example in class.

I would be grateful for any kind of help! Especially with the second part.

Thank you!

Comment: How is $f$ defined for $x\in (1,\,2)$?

Comment: Look up the even extension of f(x) to $-1\le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove your sum note that $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2+1}=\frac{i}{2}\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac{1}{n\pi+i}-\frac{1}{n\pi-i}\right)=\frac{i}{2}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{n\pi+i}.$$Taking the log-derivative of $$\sin s=s\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\left(1-\frac{s}{n\pi}\right)$$gives $$\cot s=\frac{1}{s}-\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{n\pi-s}.$$The case $s=-i$ gives $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2+1}=\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{-i}-\cot(-i)\right)=\frac{\coth 1-1}{2}=\frac{\frac{e^2+1}{e^2-1}-1}{2}=\frac{1}{e^2-1}.$$

Comment: I should think it is required to see the sum coming from the Fourier series or the Plancheral theorem.

Comment: @Paul If the OP edits in a calculation of Fourier coefficients, or enough clarification on the definition of $f$ for me to get them, I'll edit my answer to show such a treatment of this equation, in addition to or in lieu of my existing treatment. To be honest, I want even sure whether the OP wanted to get this from a Fourier series or vice versa.

Comment: @J.G. Sorry for that! I put my calculated series in the post now. Concerning your statement on "the clarification on the definition of $f$": What I have written above, is everything that is on my problem sheet... But I would be very grateful if you would show how to calculate the sum from the Fourier series!

Comment: @J.G. Yes, it is $a_0=\frac{1}{2}\sinh (2)$. But I dont really see, how you get $\frac{2e}{e^2 -1}=\frac{1}{\sinh(2)}$?

Comment: @TwoStones Sorry, I meant $\frac{2e^2}{e^4-1}$. But then $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{1+\pi^2n^2}=\frac{1}{\sinh 2}-\frac14=\frac{2e^2}{e^4-1}-\frac14=\frac{1+8e^2-e^4}{4(e^4-1)},$$so that still doesn't work. Is it possible one of the $\sinh 2$ factors in your result was meant to be something else?

Comment: @J.G. I checked my resulsts via WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(pi+n+x)+cosh(x-1)+dx+from+-1+to+1. I dont see any mistakes, since $\sin(\pi n) =0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @TwoStones Your mistake is in neglecting the sine integrals. Remember, $f(x)=\cosh 1\cosh x-\sinh 1\sinh x$ isn't an even function on the period $[-1,\,1]$.

Comment: @J.G. I see. But I have to find a cosine series (i.e. an even series). How am I supposed to that?

Comment: @TwoStones You'd have to define $f$ to be an even function in the first place, e.g. $f(x)=\cosh (1-x)$ on $[0,\,1]$ requires $f(x)=\cosh(1-|x|)$ on $[-1,\,1]$. But then you'll find the integrals update accordingly.

Comment: @J.G. Ok, yeah I see that. But is there any way you can calcute the sum using the Fourier-series of $f$?

Comment: @TwoStones Once you have the revised series for the even $f$, I imagine the strategy I've described above would work just fine. If you edit the question again to show the result of that, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92972/discussion-between-twostones-and-j-g).